# Embedding pure python(Cpython) on android

Tags: python, android, ffmpeg, embed, youtube-dl

I want to create movie download app for android for learn.
To make develop easily, I would like to use youtube-dl for downloader backend.

So I want to embed Cpython runtime and ffmpeg (for convert movie format) to Android app.
Is it able to do with android NDK?

Note that I know more better ways are exist.(like use java-friend python runtime  or downloader implement as online server)

But I want to try to embed python and ffmpeg in app for learn.

Can it with Android NDK?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use Python in an Android app. There are in fact several apps like Pydroid and QPython on Google Play that use Python.

[Check out this tutorial](http://joaoventura.net/blog/2014/python-android-1/)